# How to delete thread messages in row via Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I try to write function which would delete message in Gmail thread with several messages.

```
function movetotrash()
{
 var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0]; // Get first thread in inbox
  if (thread==null)
  {}  
  else
  {
   
    var message = thread.getMessages()[0]; // Get the latest message   
  
   Logger.log('zero'+thread.getMessages()[0].getPlainBody());
    message.moveToTrash()
  }
}
```

I can see that message disappeared in gmail interface.
But when I call this function again I can see that message [0] is the same

Comment: If you actually want to delete them why not use Gmail Rest API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the email moved to the trash can still be retrieved with `var message = thread.getMessages()[0]`. By this, after you run the script, you can retrieve the same message with `var message = thread.getMessages()[0]`. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.
- If you want to use `moveToTrash()`, how about checking whether the email is in the trash? In this case, you can use `isInTrash()`.

When the above points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```js
var message = thread.getMessages()[0]; // Get the latest message

ogger.log('zero'+thread.getMessages()[0].getPlainBody());
message.moveToTrash()
```

##### To:

```js
var messages = thread.getMessages();
for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
  if (messages[i].isInTrash()) continue;
  Logger.log(messages[i].getPlainBody());
  messages[i].moveToTrash();
  break;
}
```

- By this modification, the message is moved to the trash every run.

#### Sample script:

From your title of `How to delete thread messages in row via Google Apps Script?`, if you want to delete all messages of the thread, you can also use the following script.

Before you use this script, [please enable Gmail API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 1)[0]; // Get first thread in inbox
if (thread) {
  Gmail.Users.Threads.remove("me", thread.getId());
}
```

- **This script deletes the thread. So when you test this, please test the script using the sample thread. Please be careful this.**

#### References:

- [isInTrash()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#isintrash)
- [Method: users.threads.delete](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.threads/delete)

Answer (score 0):

Use isInTrash() on each message.

```js
function movetotrash()
{
 var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0]; // Get first thread in inbox
  if (thread==null)
  {}  
  else
  {
   
    i=0
    while (thread.getMessages()[i].isInTrash()) i++
    var message = thread.getMessages()[i]; // Get the latest not in trash message   
  
   Logger.log('zero'+thread.getMessages()[i].getPlainBody());
    message.moveToTrash()
  }
}
```